# Possible approach to sentiment analysis (I apologize, I'm very new to NLP)

Tags: nlp, abstract-syntax-tree, sentiment-analysis

So I have an idea for classifying sentiments of sentences talking about a given brand product (in this case, pepsi). Basically, let's say I wanted to figure out how people feel about the taste of pepsi. Given this problem, I want to construct abstract sentence templates, basically possible sentence structures that would indicate an opinion about the taste of pepsi. Here's one example for a three word sentence:

```
[Pepsi] [tastes] [good, bad, great, horrible, etc.]
```

I then look through my database of sentences, and try to find ones that match this particular structure. Once I have this, I can simply extract the third component and get a sentiment regarding this particular aspect (taste) of this particular entity (pepsi).

The application for this would be looking at tweets, so this might yield a few tweets from the past year or so, but it wouldn't be enough to get an accurate read on the general sentiment, so I would create other possible structures, like:

```
[I] [love, hate, dislike, like, etc.] [the taste of pepsi]
[I] [love, hate, dislike, like, etc.] [the way pepsi tastes]
[I] [love, hate, dislike, like, etc.] [how pepsi tastes]
```

And so on and so forth.

Of course most tweets won't be this simple, there would be possible words that would mean the same as pepsi, or words in between the major components, etc - deviations that it would not be practical to account for.

What I'm looking for is just a general direction, or a subfield of sentiment analysis that discusses this particular problem. I have no problem coming up with a large list of possible structures, it's just the deviations from the structures that I'm worried about. I know this is something like a syntax tree, but most of what I've read about them has just been about generating text - in this case I'm trying to match a sentence to a structure, and pull out the entity, sentiment, and aspect components to get a basic three word answer.

Answer (score 0):

This templates approach is the core idea behind my own sentiment mining work. You might find study of [EBMT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example-based_machine_translation) (example-based machine translation) interesting, as a similar (but under-studied) approach in the realm of machine translation.

Get familiar with Wordnet, for automatically generating rephrasings (there are hundreds of papers that build on WordNet, some of which will be useful to you). ([The WordNet book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/WordNet-Electronic-Database-Language-Communication/dp/026206197X) is getting old now, but worth at least a skim read if you can find it in a library.)

I found [Bing Liu's book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Sentiment-Analysis-Opinion-Mining-Bing-ebook/dp/B009KET3PU) a very useful overview of all the different aspects and approachs to sentiment mining, and a good introduction to further reading. (The Amazon UK reviews are so negative I wondered if it was a different book! The Amazon US reviews are more positive, though.)